# Category scale on Y-axis and time on x-axis in bubble chart in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Is is possible to have a category scale on y-axis in Bubble chart?
I am trying to create a bubble chart where on y-axis-> days of the week and x-axis-> time in "hh:mm a" format.  (only because Chart.js allows timescale only on the x axis). Please suggest how I can change this question to be more helpful to more people.

```
<body><canvas id="bubble" width="400" height="400"></canvas></body>

<script>


$(function() {
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#fff'
  var bubbleBackgroundColor = function() {
            return 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
  };
  var bubbleBorderColor = function() {
            return 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
  };

  var bubbleChartData = {
    animation: {
      duration: 10000
    },
    // Documentation says the tick values tick.min & tick.max must be in the Labels array. So thats what I have below
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "wed", "Thu"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Requests and bookings",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: bubbleBackgroundColor(),
      borderColor: bubbleBorderColor(),
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(153, 102, 155, 0.2)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 155, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      // how would the data change ...how can the numbers for y be replaced with strings
      data:[{x: 2,y: 0,r: 15},{x: 3,y: 1,r: 19}, {x: 5,y: 2,r: 15}, {x: 4, y: 3,r: 18}]
    }]
  };


  var ctx = document.getElementById('bubble');
  var bubble = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: bubbleChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text:'Weekly activity'
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              // will this create y-axis with days of week?
              type: 'Category',
              position: 'bottom',
              ticks: {
                ticks.min: "Mon",
                ticks.max: "Thu"
              }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                  displayFormats: {
                      minute: 'hh:mm a'
                  }
              }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in ChartJS, and will work with the given code once a couple issues are fixed:

1. The options config, containing the scales, is within another options object. This means the options in this second layer will not take effect.

Changing this

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    display: true,
    text:'Weekly activity'
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          // will this create y-axis with days of week?
          type: 'Category',
          position: 'bottom',
          ticks: {
            ticks.min: "Mon",
            ticks.max: "Thu"
          }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
              displayFormats: {
                  minute: 'hh:mm a'
              }
          }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

to this (by removing the excess `options` block)

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
  display: true,
  text:'Weekly activity'
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        // will this create y-axis with days of week?
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        ticks: {
          ticks.min: "Mon",
          ticks.max: "Thu"
        }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            displayFormats: {
                minute: 'hh:mm a'
            }
        }
    }]
  }
}
```

remedies this issue.

2. The scale type of the x-axis is `Category`, which is not a recognized [ChartJS scale type](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales) only because of the capital letter. Renaming the type to its lowercase partner, `category`, allows it to be recognized by ChartJS.
3. The tick options are set incorrectly, and are also invalid property names, which stops ChartJS from functioning.

> Documentation says the tick values tick.min & tick.max must be in the Labels array.

As of now, `ticks.min` and `ticks.max` are optional for category scales. However, if you would like to continue to use `ticks.min` and `ticks.max`, you could do this:

Change

```
ticks: {
  ticks.min: "Mon",
  ticks.max: "Thu"
}
```

to

```
ticks: {
  min: "Mon",
  max: "Thu"
}
```

Although it was not as clear as it could have been in the official documentation, this is what is meant when the options `ticks.min` and `ticks.max` are specified - instead of having the previous `ticks.ticks.min`, we can now access our settings at `ticks.min`.

4. The labels set for the `category` axis currently affect all axes instead of only the y (category) axis. We can fix this by setting `yLabels` instead of `labels`, as [shown in the documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-category-scale).

Change

```
labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "wed", "Thu"],
```

to

```
yLabels: ["Mon", "Tue", "wed", "Thu"],
```

5. Having both the x and y axes on the bottom produces a garbled chart. This can be remedied by moving the y-axis back to the left.

Change

```
type: 'category',
position: 'bottom',
ticks: {
```

to

```
type: 'category',
position: 'left',
ticks: {
```

It now looks something like this:

[image: Picture of the codepen sample]

We now have a working bubble chart! The y-axis shows days of the week, and the x-axis shows a time value formatted in 'hh:mm a'. Here is the sample completed codepen: http://codepen.io/albinodrought/pen/VmNwoj

---

In response to the reasoning for this way of graphing,

> (only because Chart.js allows timescale only on the x axis)

There also seems to be workarounds for plotting timescale values on the y-axis: [ChartJS issue #2791](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2791)

Mainly, setting the y-value of your datapoints to a time-formattable value (epoch), and then changing the callback of your y-axis to format those values. See the [ChartJS docs for setting tick callbacks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-creating-custom-tick-formats).

Comment: for some reason i currently do not understand, the above mentioned solutions has one drawback: The data is not being matched based on the y-axis, the weekdays. When you go to codepen.io and change just the first data object from {x: 2,y: 0,r: 15} to {x: 2,y: 4,r: 15} the data point will remain in the first "row" near Monday, but it should change to Thursday. I am currently coping with this issue, too, and didn't find any workaround.

Comment: @AlbinoDrought: Hi, thanks for your solution, is there anyway to use x: moment(something) ? I didn't manage to have the proper x data altough my moment object is right.

Comment: In the codepen example if the y is changed to the string equivalent it works for me. ie {x: 2,y: 'Mon',r: 15}

Answer (score 0):

Please try
data:

```
[ {x: '2016-05-11 12:00:00', y: 'Mon', r: 15}, {x: '2016-05-11 20:00:00', y: 'Sat', r: 20}, {x: '2016-05-11 05:00:00', y: 'Wed', r: 5} ]
```

Instead of
data:

```
[{x: 2,y: 0,r: 15},{x: 3,y: 1,r: 19}, {x: 5,y: 2,r: 15}, {x: 4, y: 3,r: 18}]
```